# GPIO number and hardware relation

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, gpio

In the linux GPIO subsystem:

`static int gpio_request(unsigned gpio, const char *label)`

GPIO number is taken from hardware schematics right?? How exactly this number is mapped to dts (or any header file in linux kernel)? Can I use GPIO number from schematics directly or do I need to add some offset?

I am using CN8300 cavium arm soc. And trying to convert a GPIO pin into interrupt pin.

Comment: It depends on the configured GPIO library. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/driver-api/gpio/board.html

Comment: @stark, there is no mention of v4.17, why not to give a link to the latest and greatest version of the documentation?